# WIth PHP 5.6 and PDO is there any need for escaping characters?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I use PDO to read/enter MySQL data in order to prevent SQL-Injection

```
$stmt = $DBH->prepare("SELECT * FROM T_Users WHERE User_Name = :UN");
$stmt->bindParam(':UN', $user_name);
$stmt->execute();
```

Are there any reasons I should be escaping characters before entering them in the database or before displaying the data from the database in the browser? Can malicious people exploit my website or other users by perhaps recording JavaScript code to my database?

Thanks!

Comment: You should _not_ escape anything manually in that situation. The data binding does the escaping, if you additionally escape manually you will end up with "double escaped" characters. Not what you want. That is all actually explained in the documentation.

Comment: By using Prepared, Parameterized Queries you're already taking care of SQL Injections. There is no need to escape anything anymore.

Comment: What if a malicious user chooses his username to be JavaScript code - can that harm other users if they get his username displayed in their browser? Maybe I am just being too paranoid...

Comment: Yes, but then you need to html encode what you want to output, e.g. with `htmlspecialchars`. Sanitizing is still an option before inserting into database.

Answer (score 2):

The `->prepare();` method, along with `bindParam()`does everything for you, so there's no need to do anything else.

When you bind a param to the prepared statement variable, it puts the raw data in rather than adding it to the query like the old ways of doing it! :)

Comment: It is not accurate to say that there is escaping happening: in fact there isn't.  The `prepare` method does not escape anything, as it does not even know the values at that point. They are bound later, and *not* escaped, not even by the middle-ware.

Comment: @trincot Albeit `PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES` does in fact escape the values after binding them. (Which of course, it shouldn't have to; but it's the default still.)

Answer (score 2):

You should certainly not escape the arguments you pass for binding parameters.

There is no escaping happening at all. It is the SQL engine that compiles the statement with place-holders, and receives the parameter values separately, unescaped, later. It is the capability of the SQL engine to combine the compiled statement (there is no more SQL string at this point) and the parameter values that ensures that the whole problem of SQL injection has become irrelevant.

Escaping values that you pass for binding place holders would have a negative effect. The SQL engine really needs the values as they are, and if they are escaped in some way, the engine will not unescape them, but take them literally.